# Boku No Hero Academia: all heroes / sidekicks in stain arc

Tags: my-hero-academia

Does anyone know all the heroes not named in the Stain arc? Episodes 16 - 17 in the anime and chapters 51-53 in the magna. e.g. the guy that is like a minotaur, the two ninjas, etc

Comment: have you tried looking up character wikis for their "first appeared in episode #xx"?

Comment: @Hakase yup, but these are all unnamed characters as far as I could tell - at least for the english references, so I am wondering if there might have been more in the Japanese magna